# How to mount a Shared Storage volume to a Docker container in Jelastic?

Tags: docker, mount, jelastic

I am using a Docker container in Jelastic. This Docker container has a Dashboard application. For this application, I'd like to load data in the container from a Shared Data Storage that I implemented in the same Jelastic environment.

One way I've tried is to use Mount Points. This initially seemed to work. I have done the following:

- Mount point (name): /usr/src/dashapp/,
- NFS server: Shared storage,
- Remote path: data.

So this had the effect that the data in my data storage were available in my container. However, when I checked the next day, the Docker files seemed gone and to not support the mounted volume.

Would anyone have a suggestion how to use Mount Points with a Docker container (if it is possible). Other ways to load / access data in a Jelastic Docker container would be welcome as well.

Comment: Could you please give us the name of your environment and the hoster? We will investigate the case.

Comment: Does your reply imply that I have done it in the right way? I can give you environment and hoster by email, could you give me an address?

Comment: The described behavior was not reproduced on our lab, thus it is required to take a closer look. You can contact us at https://jelastic.com/contact/